# Proximal Operator of $ \lambda \left\| W \right\|_1 + \gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} \left\| G_i \right\|_2 $ ($ {L}_{1} $ Norm and Group Regularization)

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, machine-learning, proximal-operators

Hellow everyone.

I have function 
$g(W)=\lambda |W|_1 + \gamma \sum_{i=1}^{k} ||G_i||_2$
where $|W| \in R^{m \times T}$  and $G_i \in R^T$, which is preselected rows of $|W|$.
I would like to compute the proximal of the $g(W)$
I was wondering whether can someone help me to drive the proximal of $g(W)$

Comment: What would be the effect of $ {G}_{i} $ on the Proximal Operator? The function is of $ W # any other component won't have any effect (Like adding a constant).